Can be same MAC address in different VLAN?
L3 Switch have two VLAN (VLAN 1, VLAN 2)
VLAN 1 : xxx.xxx.xxx.64/26,
VLAN 2 : xxx.xxx.xxx.192/26
L2 Switch is connected to two machines (A, B)
/ A set VLAN 1
/ B set VLAN 2
can this machines have same MAC address?

This question is basically answered here:
Will duplicated MAC address give problems, if in different VLANs?
The short answer is basically yes, it will be fine if the layer 3 and layer 2 switches isolate the VLANs correctly.
